# How to select gaps in my sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to write down a select to show me all the items that do not exist in my database. Say I have a table named TBL795 with a column named NRBEM which could not have any gaps in it.

Should be this way:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Those numbers are in sequence.

If they looked like this:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

they would be wrong, because some items have not being inserted into the table.

In a table with thousand of items it would be very difficult to find out if there are any gaps and which are the missing items.

One solution would be this:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTE ( 
  NRBEM VARCHAR(15))
```

feed it with a command like this:

```
INSERT INTO TESTE 
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(NRBEM) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT NRBEM+1 FROM cnt WHERE NRBEM <100000) 
SELECT NRBEM FROM cnt A
```

and running this select

```
SELECT A.NRBEM FROM TESTE A LEFT JOIN TBL795 B 
ON A.NRBEM = B.NRBEM
WHERE B.NRBEM IS NULL
```

I can see all the items that are missing in my table.

Since the command:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE
      cnt(NRBEM) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT NRBEM+1 FROM cnt WHERE NRBEM <100000) 
    SELECT NRBEM FROM cnt
```

create a virtual table I would like to run a select like this:

```
SELECT NRBEM FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(NRBEM) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT NRBEM+1 FROM cnt WHERE NRBEM <100000) 
SELECT NRBEM FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN TBL795 B
ON A.NRBEM = B.NRBEM
```

But this does not work.

This way:

```
SELECT X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X <100000) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN TBL795 B
ON A.X = B.NRBEM
```

it works, but does not select the right items.

So, how could I write this select?

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to use an outer join and filter out matches, but using set operations is simpler:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CNT(NRBEM) AS (...)
SELECT NRBEM
FROM CNT
WHERE NRBEM NOT IN (SELECT NRBEM
                    FROM tbl795);
```

Comment: In fact the first attempt was using NOT IN but it didn't work then I moved to LEFT JOIN. But now after I found out that what was missing was the cast to number I rewrote the first select like this: SELECT X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(40) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X <50 ) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) WHERE X NOT IN ( SELECT CAST( NRBEM AS NUMBER ) FROM TBL795
WHERE NRBEM >= 40 AND NRBEM <= 50 )
and it worked also.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was doing wrong.

If I cast nrbem as number the select works.

```
SELECT A.X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(1) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X <100000) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CAST( NRBEM AS NUMBER ) AS NRBEM FROM TBL795 ) B
ON A.X = B.NRBEM
WHERE B.NRBEM IS NULL
```

If I want to check the range from item 2400 to 2700 to see if there are any gaps I can do this:

```
SELECT A.X FROM (
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(X) AS (VALUES(2400) UNION ALL SELECT X+1 FROM cnt WHERE X < (2700)) 
SELECT X FROM cnt ) A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CAST( NRBEM AS NUMBER ) AS NRBEM FROM TBL795 WHERE NRBEM >= 2400 and nrbem <= 2700 ) B
ON A.X = B.NRBEM
WHERE B.NRBEM IS NULL
LIMIT ( 2700 - 2400 + 1 )
```